# Non durable subscriptions does not disapear on ServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, amqp, spring-jms

In spring, I'm using JMS and amqp to listen to Azure Service Bus topics by creating non durable subscription.
I'm using a method annotated with `@JmsListener`.
The topic subscription is created when I launch my service and destroyed when i shut it down.

But every hour, a warn log entry says the amqp token is expired.
Another subscription is then created and my service keeps listening to the topic, this function well.
The problem is that the previous subscription, not used anymore, is not destroyed.

This creates a lot of unused subscriptions that should not exist.

I've tried with spring `containerFactory`and the  `azure-service-bus-jms` library, same result.

I would like to know if there is a way to make the unused subscription auto destroy as the one in use do when I shut down the service.

Answer (score 0):

The access token refresh mechanism is as expected. 60 minutes is the default interval.

As for the unused subscriptions, if the subscription is non-durable, they should be deleted by the service upon AMQP link detach (disconnect of the consumer). There is also a mechanism called "auto-delete-on-idle" for Azure ServiceBus which will clean up these subscriptions after they have been idle and unused for X minutes. Overall, you probably would not need to be worried about them unless you are running into specific errors due to the subscriptions not getting cleaned up immediately.